# Youtube video using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

this is the code for 3 youtube videos which on click of a image/button pops up a youtube video

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal"   data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/loFtozxZG0s">VIDEO</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <div>
                        <iframe class = "size" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal1" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tIBxavsiHzM">VIDEO</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <div>
                        <iframe class="size" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal2" data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE">VIDEO</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <div>
                        <iframe class="size" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```css
iframe.size
{
    width: 800px;
    height:550px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
}
```

javascript:

```js
autoPlayYouTubeModal();
function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
    var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
    trigger.click(function () {
        var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
            videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-theVideo"),
            videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
        $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
            $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        });
    });
}
```

so from the above code i am unable to create or play 3 individual videos on button click.is there a solution to this

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/47dmx2b3/) fiddle.

The only things I changed was your youtube links had "http", not "https", so you were probably getting mixed content errors in the console.

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal2" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE">VIDEO</a>
```

Comment: jsfiddle has options to reference the dependencies needed for this code to work. If you are running the code locally, or elsewhere outside of jsfiddle, you need to ensure you are referencing the correct resources needed. Bootstrap has to be loaded, since you are using bootstrap modals, and also jQuery.

Comment: it works fine locally after adding a missing piece of code, is there a way of preventing the modal from closing on backdrop click and the close button should flicker or glow when the user clicks elsewhere when the video is playing..is there a possibility

Comment: Yes, add `data-backdrop='static'` to your modal div to keep the background from closing the modal. Not sure about the close button, maybe apply some custom css using focus and blur?